# Open dataset(s) with centroids or other geometry for WOEIDs?

Tags: data, geometry, download, geoplanet

The Yahoo! GeoPlanet data is [available for download](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/data/) but this data only includes the object hierarchies without any associated geometry.

Do anyone know if there is an open source for geometry (centroids or otherwise) for associated WOEIDs? I wonder if there's a lesser-known link somewhere on the GeoPlanet site, or perhaps another party has done some work to correlate open data sets (census, geonames, etc) with WOEIDs.

A WOEID (Where on Earth IDentifier) is a unique reference identifier assigned by Yahoo! to identify any feature on Earth.

Comment: While we can retrieve the coordinates for a WOEID using the API, the TOS of service is unclear on whether they can be stored.

Comment: A WOEID (Where on Earth IDentifier) is a unique reference identifier assigned by Yahoo! to identify any feature on Earth.

Answer (score 1):

I know you can either retrieve Centroids or Bounding Boxes using the API...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<place yahoo:uri="http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/2507854" xml:lang="en">  
  <woeid>2507854</woeid>  
  <placeTypeName code="7">Town</placeTypeName>  
  <name>Trenton</name>  
  <country type="Country" code="US">United States</country>  
  <admin1 type="State" code="NJ">New Jersey</admin1>  
  <admin2 type="County" code="">Mercer</admin2>  
  <admin3/>  
  <locality1>Trenton</locality1>  
  <locality2/>  
  <postal/>  
  <centroid>  
    <latitude>40.21777</latitude>  
    <longitude>-74.759361</longitude>  
  </centroid>  
  <boundingBox>  
    <southWest>  
      <latitude>40.183868</latitude>  
      <longitude>-74.819519</longitude>  
    </southWest>  
    <northEast>  
      <latitude>40.248291</latitude>  
      <longitude>-74.728798</longitude>  
    </northEast>  
  </boundingBox>  
</place>
```

Which shows the centroid and the Bottom Left and Top Right of the Bounding Box.

The GeoPlanet download - does not seem to have this information (unfortunately)

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/api_docs.html#response_formats